# Understanding java.io library

Tags: java, model, java-io

It is since yesterday I'm reading to [Java on-line documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) and I noticed that it focuses **more on practice** than describing the mechanism of that library.

Since there are a **lot** of classes in IO package, how can I understand when use and **how** use them? I'm more interested in its **model** than its content.
Advices and manual are welcomed.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I suggest to read this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: I'm reading it, but it is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: There are lot of websites,blogs and articles on internet. Which will help you to solve your doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic term of java IO is stream. Input streams allow reading, output streams allow writing. JDK provides an hierarchy of "simple" streams, e.g. `FileInputStream`, streams that you can obtain from socket, URL connection etc.

There are streams that provide additional functionality and implement wrapper (decorator) design pattern. You can use them to wrap any other stream. For example `BufferedInputStream`, `ObjectOutputStream` etc.

There is a hierarchy of readers and writers that can be created over target streams and work in terms of characters instead of bytes.

Now you are ready to back to the online documentation. Keep reading and good luck. Come back here when you have concrete questions and we will be glad to assist you.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'll try to read it more carefully.